# Why import and use of CoreLocation works without adding CoreLocation framework to project?

Tags: ios, frameworks, core-location

I created a universal framework for ios. In the framework i have a class which provide the gps position. This class uses the *import CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h*. But the CoreLocation framework should not part of my own framework. So i have to check if the framework exists. To provide this, i use the NSClassFromString like in the example.

But this example also works if i never added the CoreLocation either to my own framework nor to the app which uses my framework. Why does it work? And is this maybe a reason to reject the app in apple review?

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
...
-(void)init {
    self = [super init];
    Class CLLocationManagerOrNil = NSClassFromString(@"CLLocationManager");    
    if (CLLocationManagerOrNil) {
        _locationManager = [[CLLocationManagerOrNil alloc] init];
        _locationManager.delegate = self;

        // update location
        [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Are you using Xcode 5 by any chance?

Comment: i am using XCode 4.6.3.

Answer (score 0):

`#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>` is allowed even you didn't add `CoreLocation` framework. What is more, you can add all system framework if you want.

**But They are not working! You will get error like**

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLLocationManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

In your code, It never get inside of `if (CLLocationManagerOrNil)` block, that is why you think it is working.